# Fluidity in drag event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

Moving fast the mouse on an element the onmousemove event is not triggered every pixel the mouse moves.So how does drag in javascript come fluid?

Comment: modern dnd doesn't use onmousmove at all... that said, what you describe is a performance problem, and you can improve perf in a few ways. the dnd core must be fast (shop around), or you can hide the element being drug except for a border, which if you normally have partial opacity and shadows, will improve the "framerate" a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answare.In what way is modern dnd implemented?